# Get user's default UI language using user token with C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, localization

I know that [GetUserDefaultUILanguage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318137%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API can retrieve the UI language identifier for the current user, but I need to call it from a service and find out the UI of a specific user by its user token. Is such possible?

Comment: Why are you doing user-specific things in a service?

Comment: To make long story short, the service needs to ensure that all user-mode files are properly removed when specific operation is finished but to make file names I need to know the UI of the user account. (This is a fail-safe mechanism in case such removal is not finished by a user-mode process.) But, this is beside the point of the question...

Comment: No, it's entirely relevant to the point of the question. If someone says "I want to do Xyz" it is entirely valid to say "why oh WHY do you want to do Xyz?" It seems to me that such a fail safe has little point, but I don't know the specifics.

Comment: @ahmd0: up to (not including) Vista, a replacement GINA could be what you're looking for and then a credential provider on newer Windows versions. It would allow you to "monitor" things from logon to logoff.

Answer (score 0):

A service runs under some account, so even if you could successfully call functions like this, they'd tell you about the account the service is running under, not the account of a user that might need the service to carry out operations on its behalf.

As such, you probably need to have the user program register itself (e.g., PID and UI language) with the service. The service can then store those and use them as needed.

Comment: Session separation, more than anything would be a problem here. So it would depend whether the function internally reads the registry to retrieve the information. If it does, impersonation with loading the user's hive (unless it already is) is a viable route to take.

Comment: @0xC0000022L: You seem (IMO, anyway) to have a pretty loose definition of "viable". First you suggest a solution that's been obsolete for years, then allowing a service to impersonate a normal user? (and apparently down-voting because somebody realizes that's a *horrible* idea)?

Comment: which one has been obsolete for years, credential providers? For the GINA I pointed it out myself and gave the modern alternative. Besides, there are *plenty* of XP and 2003 systems still in use as of today and the OP didn't specify for which OS(s) this was for.

Answer (score 0):

To use functions like `GetUserDefaultUILanguage()` inside a service, it needs to be running as that user.  Either set the service in the SCM to run under that specific user account, or else have its code impersonate the user dynamically when needed.

Comment: Will impersonation reflect user's UI? So far the only way I could come up with was spawning a small user-mode process to run that API and send the data back to the service.